# C# Clear richTextBox in Timer

Tags: c#, timer, save, richtextbox

I want to save richTextBox.Text every minute, when user checked save checkbox.

here checkbox event.

num_saveTime is numericUpDown control for inpute minute.

save_timer is global variable.

```
private void chk_save_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chk_save.Checked)
    {
          num_saveTime.Enabled = false;
          save_timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
          save_timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(save_timer_Elapsed);
          save_timer.Interval = 250;
          save_timer.Start();
     }
     else
     {
          num_saveTime.Enabled = true;
          save_timer.Stop();
     }
}
```

and Timer Event

```
delegate void TimerDelegate(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e);
void save_timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (rtxb_PKT.InvokeRequired)
    {
         TimerDelegate tdel = new TimerDelegate(save_timer_Elapsed);
         rtxb_PKT.Invoke(tdel, new object[] { sender, e });
    }
    else
    {
         string now_ss = DateTime.Now.ToString("ss");
         if (now_ss.Equals("00"))
         {
             string now_mm = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm");
             string save_mm = Convert.ToInt32(num_saveTime.Value).ToString("D2");
             if (save_mm.Equals(now_mm))
             {
                 string path = Application.StartupPath + @"\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd--HH-mm-sss") + ".rtf";
                 rtxb_PKT.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
                 rtxb_PKT.Clear(); //----here
              }
         }
     }
}
```

I want clear richTextBox after save.

But I insert .Clear() that position, it clear text before save, so file is empty...

How can I clear it after saving?

Comment: Could be that you save twice? The first time everything is fine, then you clear and save the empty rtxb again.

Comment: The timer tick event (interval 250ms) is fired too *frequently* for a task that runs on UI thread. Imaging that your file will be saved four! times within a second.

Comment: And worse, there is no guarantee that any Elapsed event is fired within that second {save_mm:00}, even if you set the interval as 250ms!  The UI thread might be busy within that second, so your save logic can be postponed to the next hour.

Comment: you're right. I increased interval, it save well....